# Keyword arguments

Tags: python, django

I am trying different types of views for practice and I am getting following error message in Django 1.5:-

```
context = super(HelloTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
NameError: global name 'kwargs' is not defined.
```

My urls.py for project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^hello/$', 'article.views.hello'),
    url(r'^hello_template/$', 'article.views.hello_template'),
    url(r'^hello_template_simple/$', 'article.views.hello_template_simple'),
    url(r'^hello_class_view/$', HelloTemplate.as_view()),
    )
```

My Views.py: -

```
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.template.loader import get_template
    from django.template import Context
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
    from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

    def hello(request):
        name = 'Mudassar'
        html = "<html><body>Hi %s, this seems to worked!</body></html>" % name
        return HttpResponse(html)

    def hello_template(request):
        name = 'Mudassar'
        t = get_template('hello.html')
        html = t.render(Context({'name': name}))
        return HttpResponse(html)
    def hello_template_simple(request):
        name = 'Mudassar'
        return render_to_response('hello.html', {'name':name})

    class HelloTemplate(TemplateView):
        template_name = 'hello_class.html'

        def get_context_data(self, **kwarg):
            context = super(HelloTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['name'] = 'Mudassar'
            return context
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the parameter in `get_context_data` is named `kwarg` and you're referring to it by `kwargs` (in plural).

I suggest you to use `kwargs` in plural since [is more standard](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/) :)

Answer (score 2):

Replace :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwarg):
    context = super(HelloTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['name'] = 'Mudassar'
    return context
```

With :

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HelloTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['name'] = 'Mudassar'
    return context
```

:) :P

Comment: That did the trick...thanks a lot guys..appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same variable you are passing.

```
class HelloTemplate(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'hello_class.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HelloTemplate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['name'] = 'Mudassar'
        return context
```

If you want to use `kwargs` then pass `kwargs` if you want to use `kwarg` then pass same in super.